# Merging multiple dataframes and summing duplicate columns

Tags: r

I have spent a good deal of time looking around and cannot find a solution to my specific question. I would really appreciate any help.

I have a list of csv files that all have a column containing species names (titled "Row" in the example below). Each csv file also has a range of samples, some of which are unique across all of the csv files and some of which are present in a number of csv files. I am looking for a way to merge all of these csv files on the "Row" variable while also summing any sample that appears in multiple csv files.

As an example:

```
dfrm_1 <- data.frame(a = c("species1", "species2", "species3", "species9"), b= c(100,5,24,100), c=c(52,151,15,100))
dfrm_2 <- data.frame(a = c("species2", "species4", "species6", "species9"), b= c(4,2,500,100), c=c(67,98,153,100))
names(dfrm_1) <- c("Row", "S1", "S2")
names(dfrm_2) <- c("Row", "S2", "S4")

mDF <- merge(dfrm_1, dfrm_2, by="Row", all=TRUE)
```

When the two data frames are merged, Sample 2 (S2, which is present in both data frames) becomes S2.x and S2.y. Instead of the merge function adding the letter suffix, I would like to just sum the two columns.

The desired output is:

```
df_merge <- data.frame(a=c("species1", "species2", "species3", "species9", "species4", "species6"), b=c(100,5,24,100,0,0), c=c(52,155,15,200,2,500), d=c(0,67,0,100,98,153))
names(df_merge) <- c("Row", "S1", "S2", "S4")
```

Note: edited to expand example and to include desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, however, instead of merging the data you want to append the data.  The code below will get you what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
rbind_list(dfrm_1, dfrm_2) %>%
  group_by(Row) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  unique()
```

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, I have edited my original question to provide the desired output. The code you have here is very close, but when I try it on an expanded example that has more than one common species, it does not sum them all correctly. For example, in the updated example code above, species2 sums correctly to a total of 155 but species9 gives a sum of 100 when it should be 200.